# Build Number can be lower on restart of remotebuild server using VS Tools for Cordova

Tags: versioning, visual-studio-cordova

When you submit a build it creates a build number which is random(?) and can be lower that a previous one generated in a previous session.

This means submitting a new version may have a lower version number that the previous and its rejected by the Apple app store

Can we have support for * in the build number in the config.xml?

Specifically to be able to auto-increment the build number so that it never gets rejected

In the app store we have two version numbers

1. display version
2. build version

Ideally (for me anyway), we could submit both like this ...

```
version 1.0
build   1.0.*
```

and the app store would get this ...

```
version 1.0
build   1.0.<VS Auto Incremented>.<Current Build Number?> (e.g. 1.0.12.7546)
```

I am not sure if  is needed, but it would make no difference to me if it were

Answer (score 0):

VS-MDA was designed to support incremental build numbers which is based on the latest bld/buildInfo.json in project folder. However for some reason your remote build server suppresses the incremental feature by returning HTTP code 202. You can work this around by modifying %APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\lib\remoteBuild.js as follows:

```js
function submitBuildRequestToServer(settings, appAsTgzStream) {
    ...
    //if (settings.isIncrementalBuild) {
        var buildInfo = require(buildInfoFilePath);
        incrementalBuildNumber = buildInfo.buildNumber + 1;
        buildUrl += '&buildNumber=' + incrementalBuildNumber;
    //}
    ...
}
```